# Can't set group policy settings on PC's with different language settings

Tags: c++, windows, group-policy

In my program, I have to set the group policy setting of certain files to `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES`. To accomplish this, I'm using the following function which takes the `FilePath` to a file and sets the `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` group policy on that file:

```
DWORD AdjustGroupPolicy(std::wstring wstrFilePath)
{
    PACL pOldDACL = NULL, pNewDACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS eaAccess;
    SECURITY_INFORMATION siInfo = DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
    DWORD dwResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    dwResult = GetNamedSecurityInfo(wstrFilePath.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pOldDACL, NULL, &pSD);
    if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        if (pSD != NULL)
            LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSD);
    }

    ZeroMemory(&eaAccess, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    eaAccess.grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_EXECUTE;
    eaAccess.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    eaAccess.grfInheritance = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
    eaAccess.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
    eaAccess.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    eaAccess.Trustee.ptstrName = L"ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES";

    dwResult = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &eaAccess, pOldDACL, &pNewDACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwResult)
    {
        if (pSD != NULL)
            LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSD);
        if (pNewDACL != NULL)
            LocalFree((HLOCAL)pNewDACL);
    }

    dwResult = SetNamedSecurityInfo((LPWSTR)wstrFilePath.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, siInfo, NULL, NULL, pNewDACL, NULL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwResult)
    {
        if (pSD != NULL)
            LocalFree((HLOCAL)pSD);
        if (pNewDACL != NULL)
            LocalFree((HLOCAL)pNewDACL);
    }

    return dwResult;
}
```

The problem is, some users are reporting that this function is failing for some reason. After digging into the issue a bit, I found that on PC's with languages settings other than English, the function fails at `SetEntiresInAcl` with the error code 1332 (0x534). In the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385(v=vs.85).aspx), the error code corresponds to the error `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED`, with the description:

> No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

My guess is that the error is thrown because `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` is named something differently depending on the language settings and thus Windows can't find the security ID for it; however, I'm unsure of how to fix this error. How could I go about fixing this error so that the function works reliably regardless of the users language settings?

Comment: The SID for `ALL_APP_PACKAGES` is S-1-15-2-1. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm relatively new to access control policies in Windows and never had to deal with it before my current project. I've learned a lesson that I shouldn't set the Trustee by name since you can't rely on the name being the same across systems, even if it's a well-known group.

I ended up fixing it by adding the following code to the function:

```
PSID pSID;
ConvertStringSidToSid(L"S-1-15-2-1", &pSID); // S-1-15-2 is the SID for ALL_APP_PACKAGES
```

Later when I set the Trustee info, I changed the code to:

```
eaAccess.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
eaAccess.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
eaAccess.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)pSID;
```

[`ConvertStringSidToSid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376402(v=vs.85).aspx) takes the string-format SID and returns a pointer to the corresponding SID struct. I can then use that SID instead of using it's name, which avoids the translation issue I was having before.